# gdb printing a __m256i as 8x 32-bit elements instead of the default 4x 64-bit?

Tags: integer, gdb, intrinsics, avx

I use **gdb** to debug a program that uses **AVX2** intrinsics via `immintrin.h` header.

With gdb, I can print out `__m256` values without any issues, like so:

```
>>> print scl8
$4 = {[0] = 0.0078125, [1] = 0.0078125, [2] = 0.0078125, [3] = 0.0078125, [4] = 0.0078125, [5] = 0.0078125, [6] = 0.0078125, [7] = 0.0078125}
```

In this particular example, all 8 lanes contain the value 1/128.
And note that gdb **prints out all 8 lanes**!

If I want to print out epi32 values of a `__m256i` value, things go wrong:

```
>>> print msk8
$6 = {[0] = 4294967297, [1] = 4294967297, [2] = 4294967297, [3] = 4294967297}
```

Why would gdb print 4 lanes (of what I assume are 64bit integers) for `__m256i` but 8 lanes of 32bit floats for `__m256` values? Where is the consistency in here?

**How can I print 8 epi32 values from a `__m256i` using gdb?**

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
```

Comment: GCC defines `__m256i` as `typedef unsigned long long __attribute__((vector_size(32), may_alias))`.  That's why `__m256i` prints as 4x uint64_t.  Remember that C x86 intrinsics use the same type for all SIMD-integer element widths.  Given a YMM register you can `p /x $ymm0.v8_int32`, but I'm not sure what you'd do with C intrinsics for source-level debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found easier solution but you can cast your value to `__v8si`, i.e. `(__v8si) ones` will print 8 lanes.

So probably watch expression, debugger console, or leaving non-used variables (will be optimized in release build) can help with debugging.

I would like to see some attributes or comments I can put in debug build, which can affect GDB.